# return@forEach does not seem to exit forEach{}

Tags: kotlin, foreach

The `count` is 4 at the end of the code below. I expected 0. Why is it 4? How can I get 0?

```
var count = 0;
"hello".forEach {
    if(it == 'h')
    {
        println("Exiting the forEach loop. Count is $count");
        return@forEach;
    }
    count++;
}
println("count is $count");
```

Output:

```
Exiting the forEach loop. Count is 0
count is 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return@forEach` does not exit `forEach()` itself, but the lambda passed to it ("body" of `forEach()`). Note that this lambda is executed several times - once per each item. By returning from it you actually skip only a single item, so this is similar to `continue`, not to `break`.

To workaround this you can create a label in the outer scope and return to it:

```
var count = 0;
run loop@ {
    "hello".forEach {
        if(it == 'h')
        {
            println("Exiting the forEach loop. Count is $count");
            return@loop;
        }
        count++;
    }
}
```

This is described here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/returns.html#return-at-labels

> Note that the use of local returns in previous three examples is similar to the use of `continue` in regular loops. There is no direct equivalent for `break`, but it can be simulated by adding another nesting lambda and non-locally returning from it

Comment: Thanks. I used "forEach" because it looked more concise. If I have to make it a nested loop to break, I guess I will just use good-old "for".

Comment: Yes, this is a big drawback of replacing loops with higher-order functions. But well, this is nothing really new. For example, `break` from nested loops requires adding some labels in both Kotlin and Java. Usually, in such cases I prefer to move the code to a separate function and return from it wherever I need.

Comment: I updated my answer, because it was technically incorrect. `return@forEach` does not exit `forEach()`, but the lambda that was passed to `forEach()`.

Answer (score 0):

It is 4 because the `forEach` call the lambda passed to it **for each** character in the string, so the `return@forEach` in your code return for the first element. You can use a for loop and use `break` to obtain 0.

Answer (score 0):

`return@forEach` returns from the lambda function. But the `forEach` function is a higher-order function that calls the lambda repeatedly for each item in the iterator. So when you return from the lambda, you are only returning for that single item in the iterator. It is analogous to using `continue` in a traditional for loop.

If you want to exit iteration in a higher-order function completely, you have to use labels. And as I type this, I see another answer already shows how to do that, but I'll leave this in case the different explanation helps.

Comment: This is not very convenient. Why didn't the makers of Kotlin create a "break" equivalent?

Comment: I agree, this workaround is ugly and I don't like it. But I think improving it is not that easy. Note that `forEach()` isn't some magic language construct. It is just a function and you can create your own `forEach2()` function. So how such universal `break` statement would work with totally custom functions? Well, actually I see some solution. They could provide a receiver to `forEach()` lambda and it would have `break()` function or even `val break`. But it might be a little confusing, because we would need to both `break` and `return`.

Comment: Since it is inline, the compiler could be updated to handle it with the use of annotations. As mentioned in broot’s answer, they’ve stated that they intend to support it. I don’t know why it hasn’t happened yet.

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to count the number of characters before 'h', you could do something like this:

```
val numCharsBeforeH = "hello".takeWhile { it != 'h' }.length
```

---

From your comment to Tenfour04's answer:

> This is not very convenient. Why didn't the makers of Kotlin create a "break" equivalent?

Here is a quote of the "Loops" section of the [Coding conventions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#loops):

> Prefer using higher-order functions (`filter`, `map` etc.) to loops.
> Exception: `forEach` (prefer using a regular `for` loop instead, unless
> the receiver of `forEach` is nullable or `forEach` is used as part of a
> longer call chain).
>
> When making a choice between a complex expression using multiple
> higher-order functions and a loop, understand the cost of the
> operations being performed in each case and keep performance
> considerations in mind.

Indeed, using a regular `for` loop with `break` does what you expect:

```
var count = 0;
for (char in "hello") {
    if (char == 'h') {
        println("Breaking the loop. Count is $count")
        break
    }
    count++
}
println("count is $count")
```

Output:

```
Breaking the loop. Count is 0
count is 0
```

Except for very simple operations, there are probably better ways to do what you need than using `forEach`.